# 商品の枚数を入力すると、商品の合計金額と送料、送料込の合計金額（税込）を出力するプログラム

Tags: c

Tシャツは3000円、フェイスタオルは1500円、マフラータオルは1000円という条件下で。
送料は以下のとおりです。
・合計金額（税抜）が10000円以上のときは送料無料。
・合計金額（税込）が10000円未満のときは、送料は880円
なお、消費税は10%とする。

また、実行例を以下のようにするにはどこを直せばよいでしょうか。
Tシャツの枚数：1
フェイスタオルの枚数：1
マフラータオルの枚数：1
商品の合計金額（税抜）は5500円
送料（税込）は880円
送料込の合計金額（税込）は6930円

```
int main(void)
{
   int t,f,m;
   printf("Tシャツの枚数:　");
   scanf("%d", &t);
   printf("フェイスタオルの枚数:　");
   scanf("%d", &f);
   printf("マフラータオルの枚数:　");
   scanf("%d", &m);
     if(3000*t+1500*f+1000*m<10000) {
   printf("商品の合計金額は%d円。\n" 3000*t+1500*f+1000*m);
   printf("送料は880円。\n");
   printf("送料込の合計金額(税込)は%d円。\n" 3300*t+1650*f+1100*m+880);
      }   else {
   printf("商品の合計金額は%d円。\n",3000*t+1500*f+1000*m);
   printf("送料は無料。\n");
   printf("送料込の合計金額(税込)は%d円。\n" 3300*t+1650*f+1100*m);
      }
   return 0;
}
```

ちなみにエラーは以下のように出ました。

```
$ cc ex0204.c 
ex0204.c: In function ‘main’:
ex0204.c:13:48: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
    printf("商品の合計金額は%d円。\n" 1000*t+1500*f+3000*m);
                                                ^~~~
ex0204.c:13:37: warning: format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int’ argument [-Wformat=]
    printf("商品の合計金額は%d円。\n" 1000*t+1500*f+3000*m);
                                    ~^
ex0204.c:15:59: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
    printf("送料込の合計金額(税込)は%d円。\n" 1100*t+1650*f+3300*m+880);
                                                           ^~~~
ex0204.c:15:48: warning: format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int’ argument [-Wformat=]
    printf("送料込の合計金額(税込)は%d円。\n" 1100*t+1650*f+3300*m+880);
                                               ~^
ex0204.c:19:59: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
    printf("送料込の合計金額(税込)は%d円。\n" 1100*t+1650*f+3300*m);
                                                           ^~~~
ex0204.c:19:48: warning: format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int’ argument [-Wformat=]
    printf("送料込の合計金額(税込)は%d円。\n" 1100*t+1650*f+3300*m);
                                               ~^
```

Answer (score 0):

[関数呼び出し](https://ja.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Function_call)の引数はコンマ区切りで記述します。

> 任意の完全オブジェクト型の式 (コンマ演算子はできません) のコンマ区切りのリスト。

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("商品の合計金額は%d円。\n" 3000*t+1500*f+1000*m);
```

は

```
printf("商品の合計金額は%d円。\n",3000*t+1500*f+1000*m);
```

とカンマで区切ってください。